# JS Counter To 2 Decimal Places

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

So I am developing a simple automatic counter that increases as it goes up in seconds as opposed to a goal target number and then just stating how long it takes to complete the loop.

I currently have this code for my parseFloat function, but cannot figure out how to only show 2 decimal places. Essentially, it has to look like GBP. So 1.99, 2.00, 2.01, 2.02 etc. instead of the recurring numbers.

```
    var secs = 100;
    setInterval(function() {
    var $badge = $('#nhb_01');
    $badge.text(parseFloat($badge.text())+0.01);
}, secs);
```

Any help is appreciated! I am not much of a JS coder!

Thanks :)

Current [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ScottKrieger/jehtmrj5/)

Comment: Use `toFixed(2)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `.toFixed(decimalpoints)`. And also keep in mind that the result returned from `.toFixed()` will be a `string`,

```
var secs = 100;
setInterval(function() {
    var $badge = $('#nhb_01');
    $badge.text((parseFloat($badge.text())+0.01).toFixed(2));
}, secs);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jehtmrj5/1/)

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan Not in the code. right? :) Anyway thanks for pointing it. It seems someone has corrected it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var secs = 100;

setInterval(function() {
    var $badge = $('#nhb_01');
    var text = parseFloat($badge.text())+0.01;

    $badge.text(Math.round(text*100)/100));
}, secs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

https://jsfiddle.net/g4jm68vp/

```
var secs = 100;
setInterval(function() {
    var $badge = $('#nhb_01');
    $badge.text((Math.round(parseFloat($badge.text(), 10) * 100) + 1) / 100);
}, secs);
```